# AWS libcrypto resolve messages seen when using a boto3 library, apparently after an update

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, ssl, aws, amazon-s3

I'm using the `s4cmd` package in Python which in turn uses `boto3` to communicate with a (non Amazon) S3 service.

I've started seeing these warning messages on stderr. I believe this happened after an auto update to OpenSSL, but that's just my best guess.

```
AWS libcrypto resolve: searching process and loaded modules
AWS libcrypto resolve: found static aws-lc HMAC symbols
AWS libcrypto resolve: found static aws-lc libcrypto 1.1.1 EVP_MD symbols
```

```
> openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020

> cat /etc/os-release | head -n6
NAME="Pop!_OS"
VERSION="20.10"
ID=pop
ID_LIKE="ubuntu debian"
PRETTY_NAME="Pop!_OS 20.10"
VERSION_ID="20.10"
```

Does anyone know what these messages are, if they're ignorable, and if they are how to suppress them?

The onset of these messages correlates with a lot of random SSL failures. Both in Firefox and when using `boto3`. I commonly see errors like `[Exception] Connection was closed before we received a valid response from endpoint URL` now, but when I ssh into another server I have no problem. An hour later the problems will be gone, only to reappear some apparently random time later.

**Additional info:**

I recently noticed that inside a docker container on my laptop my `boto3` & `s4cmd` commands work while they fail on my base OS. I checked `openssl version` on both:

```
# Base OS, failing
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020

# Inside docker container, working
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
```

Comment: Can you check your firewall(s)? Maybe the problem isn't in your computer.

Comment: It occurs on servers, laptops (home or office), and other peoples computers. It may also be related to the letsencrypt.org root certs expering, which also happened around this time. I noted that coincidence after posting this.